# Issues when creating new angular 7 project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, angular7

Error while creating the new project using angular cli. Tried npm clear cache --force and manually deleted the npm cache folder. None of them worked.

No proxy required for connecting internet

ng new testapp--routing

````
> node-sass@4.11.0 install C:\Users\user\testapp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall C:\Users\user\testapp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\testapp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\user\\testapp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.0.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError ```
````

Comment: you don't need to put `--routing` in `ng serve` command just use `ng new testapp` and it will auto create your `app.routing.ts` file

Comment: it does not solve the issue even if i not explicitly add routing while creating the app

Comment: Are you behind any firewall, some offices might have firewall, so you might be needing to setup the proxy first ! Check this [how to setup the proxy](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-npm-install-the-command-behind-corporate-proxy-server/) if that's your case, Might be helpful !

Comment: I am using my personal laptop with wifi, which does not need proxy to connect

Comment: Delete the angular/cli delete the cache and again install and try to create a simple new project with ng new test.
`$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 1):

Just create new project as:
    ng new testapp
Then remove your angular cli and clear cache and please again

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

And build and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes due to global installation of many library you will get the above error. No need to create new project. Please perform the following steps

Step 1: Try to do the `npm i` again. if you are ending up with error then go to step 2

Step 2: $ `npm install -g node-sass`

And finally, one last check: 
$ `node-sass -v`

Then perform step 1 again if needed ( optional).

Once the `node-sass` installation is successful then you wont face this error going forward.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I was having pretty much the same problem. I'm guessing you are selecting SCSS as the stylesheet format? I got a bit further than you before it ended in compile errors but would not work all the way. I solved my problem by downgrading to node version 11. It seems node-sass 4.11 does not support node version 12. See [Error installing node-sass](http://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1725).

The download error is shown because there is no such file. The latest version time of writing at [github](http://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.11.0) is [win32-x64-67_binding.node](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-67_binding.node).

I also think that you might have a dependency problem with Python. Have a look at [node-gyp configuration - windows](http://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) and make sure you have all the dependencies.

Hope this helps!